# How many times the function will be invoked?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I have this cycle:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
    if(i % 5 == 1 && i % 3 == 1) {
        function();
    }
}
```

How can i count amount of calls of function() without running this code?

Comment: Figure out how often a number is evenly divisible by both 3 and 5.

Answer (score 3):

I take from the `complexity-theory` tag that you want some Theta expression. The if causes your function to be executed every fifteenth time, which is a constant factor, so the number of executions is still Theta(n).

Answer (score 1):

The conditional has two expressions. The first expression holds true every 5 iterations and the second holds true every 3 iterations. Together they hold true apprx every 15 rounds and `function()` gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the values of `i` where your condition holds:

- 1
- 16
- 31
- 46
- 61
- 76
- 91
- 106
- 121
- 136
- 151
- 166
- 181
- 196
- ...

Now, what would be the case if you had the condition `i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 == 0`, it would have to be a multiple of 15 (`lcm(3,5)`) and then the condition would hold on every 15th iteration. From that you can likely derive the relation yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement is true when `i = 15*k +1` where k is whole number. For total number like that within (0,n) is given by  `k = floor((n-1)/15) + 1` for example n = 31, `k = floor((31-1)/15) + 1 = 3` which is `(1,16,31)`